# Flowtype / jQuery - Property `datepicker` Property not found in statics of function

Tags: jquery, flowtype

I have a function

```
formatDate(rawDate: ?string, inUTC: ?boolean, format: ?string): string {
    let date = rawDate ? new Date(rawDate) : new Date()
    if (!Time.isValidDate(date)) {
        return rawDate || ''
    }
    if (inUTC) {
        date = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate())
    }
    return $.datepicker.formatDate(format || Time.kDefaultDateFormat, date)
}
```

But the $.datepicker gets flagged as a flow error, Property `datepicker` Property not found in statics of function

How do I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need definitions for jQuery-UI, which don't exist as of today for Flow. In the meantime, you can access datepicker by casting `$` to any before using datepicker:

```
return ($: any).datepicker.formatDate(format || Time.kDefaultDateFormat, date)
```